# elastic4s bulk insert dont work with multiple elements in Json

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic4s

Can someone please help me, how to execute bulk insert with header "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" in elastic4s ? I have tried this

`client.execute {
      bulk(
        indexInto("cars" / "car").source(getCarsFromJson)
      ).refresh(RefreshPolicy.WaitFor)
    }.await`

It works for one element in json, but when i add another element to json, no element are added to elastic.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the right syntax? Shouldn't it say

```
"cars/car"
```

Instead of

```
"cars" / "car"
```

Comment: I think, that I need to override ElasticClient executee function and add header, can you help me with that ?

Answer (score -1):

The `source` method on `indexInto` will not support multiple json objects, because you're trying to put multiple documents inside a single document insert.

Instead, you will need to take your json, parse it into objects, and iterate over them adding an insert document for each one.

Something like the following:

```
def getCarsFromJson: Seq[String] = /// must return a sequence of json strings
val inserts = getCarsFromJson.map { car => indexInto("cars" /"car").source(car) }
client.execute {
 bulk(inserts:_*).refresh(RefreshPolicy.WaitFor)
}
```